# How do I edit my data frame (multiply columns) in R?

Tags: r, csv, edit

I have a CSV file with 11 columns (but the first 8 I am ignoring for now), last 3 (9 - 11) are important. I am missing some data for column 9, and these cells show up as NA. But to fill in these cells, I can multiply column 11 by column 10.

I want to create a data frame where all of column 9 is filled in and save that as a new CSV file. I first tried to multiply the columns. This worked and I got the missing data from column 9. Then I tried to merge the new column 9 with the column 9 from my data frame but R just attached the 2 columns together.

I would like for the NA data that has been calculated to replace the data in the original data frame (so I end up with a full column 9). Plus, I would like to only multiply the columns with NA cells so that no original data is replaced. How to do that?

```
col_9 <- matrix(dat[,10] * dat[,11], ncol=1)
print(col_9)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ifelse` function:

`dat[,9]=ifelse(is.na(dat[,9]), dat[,10]*dat[,11], dat[,9])`

If the condition is `TRUE` (i.e. `is.na(dat[,9])`), the value will be replaced by the second argument (`dat[,10]*dat[,11]`), otherwise it is replaced by the third on (i.e. `dat[,9]`, so the value is kept).